# Design pattern for mapping field from one object to another

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am writing a component that fits into a 3rd party framework.  The component exports orders into a specific file format, ready to be transported to a separate backend system.

The backend system has a very different view of the data, with specific restrictions on field lengths and formats that the framework doesnt have.  Therefore i need to be able to:

```
1. Store/know about these rules
2. Take the data from the framework
3. Transform based on the data received and the rules i mentioned in point 1
4. Write the transformed data to file
```

Are there any design patterns for this type of functionality.  Particularly, where to put the mapping rules:

```
- xml config
- directly in a class
- something else?
```

Comment: Take a look at http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is used to adapt from one interface to another.

Different ways to accomplish, but you can simply implent two interfaces on the one adapter class. And/Or make the adapter composed of an instance of another class or classes.

Comment: Also take a look at the Mediator pattern, which can be used to map in both directions.

Comment: @aRestless thats for altering behaviour, don't think its needed here

Comment: You are right. Had it wrong in mind and thought of it as kind-of-generalization of data mappers or two-way adapters.

Comment: Adapter is for the interface though isnt it? i.e. the public methods.  Not the way the object stores its data

Comment: @MartyWallace I don't udnerstand what you mean. You will need to expose the data somehow

Answer (score 0):

The Adapter pattern (more specifically Object Adapter pattern) contains an instance of the class it wraps. In this situation, the adapter makes calls to the instance of the wrapped object. The pattern itself allows the interface of an existing class to be used from another interface. Hope this helps!